# PHP Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 44 in wp-includes/class-wp.php on line number 223

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match

I am have tried everything , disable plugins , change the theme , change WordPress, change permalink to default all done still seeing that error,
That's the code for line number 223:

```
if ( preg_match( "#^$match#", $request_match, $matches ) ||
                    preg_match( "#^$match#", urldecode( $request_match ), $matches ) ) {

                    if ( $wp_rewrite->use_verbose_page_rules && preg_match( '/pagename=\$matches\[([0-9]+)\]/', $query, $varmatch ) ) { 
                        // This is a verbose page match, let's check to be sure about it.
                        $page = get_page_by_path( $matches[ $varmatch[1] ] );
                        if ( ! $page ) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        $post_status_obj = get_post_status_object( $page->post_status );
                        if ( ! $post_status_obj->public && ! $post_status_obj->protected
                            && ! $post_status_obj->private && $post_status_obj->exclude_from_search ) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    // Got a match.
                    $this->matched_rule = $match;
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: Which line is 223? What is `$match`?

Comment: it is to match permalinks structure

Comment: I am getting this error in error log

Comment: PHP Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 45 in /wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 223

Comment: Have a good day! I do not want to waste your time and my time too.